# Google replacement for CloudMqtt

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform

We have an **IoT project** here

Facts:

- We have our app running on Google App Engine, PHP runtime.
- The clients are raspberry pi or similar boards.

We are using cloudmqtt (www.cloudmqtt.com) to generate a push event on our **C** client app, which then runs the sync process with the server

**Is there a google cloud replacement for what we are doing?**

We tried Google Push/Sub, but our C app needed to be polling the service.

We would love to use Google Cloud Messaging but we could not find any way to use it for push notifications for the client.

Basically, we need to send push messages to a raspberry pi, **what would you recommend for that?** (remember our server is on GAE)

Answer (score 1):

GCM handle polling mechanisms on its own and should let you push notifications as well as messages to the client. Try debugging your application using [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/).

During I/O 2016, they also launched [Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) which is basically a newer version of GCM, and is the recommended product to use.

But if you wanted to use your deployment rather than a service, you can use Google Compute Engine instances to deploy [EMQTTD](https://github.com/emqtt/emqttd) which is a highly scalable MQTT broker written in Erlang.

Comment: Thank you! Regarding GCM/FCM how would you recommend to implement it on the raspberry pi?

Comment: I don't have enough experience in IoT to understand scope of implementation in pi, but I think it should be pretty simple since you can do it with XMPP/HTTP protocols which are supported on pi. For discussions with others who are working on something similar, join slack community: https://gcp-slack.appspot.com